# ArcSDE error: "Maximum number of connections to instance exceeded "

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I have an ArcSDE error: " **Failed to connect to database. Maximum number of connections to instance exceeded "*

Did what ESRI recommended :"

> Check the value set for the CONNECTIONS parameter in the SERVER_CONFIG
>   or sde_server_config ArcSDE system table to be sure it is sufficient.
>   If it is not, increase the number of allowed connections using the
>   sdeconfig command with the alter operation"

and still nothing works on my database server. (I can't create features, import, etc).

We use a Microsoft SQL Server. And it's an enterprise geodatabase.

---

Apparently it was a schema lock. I had a map service started which used that geodatabase. So how can I edit the geodatabase and have a started map service in the same time. I've already created several versions and tried to publish just the versions, but they still lock my gdb.

Comment: 1. what type of ArcSDE Geodatabase do you have? personal or Enterprise.. because of concurrent connections support change one to another. 2. What type operation handle on this sde?.. pls give some detailed information...

Comment: Wondering if you have [hung connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216007/how-to-determine-total-number-of-open-active-connections-in-ms-sql-server-2005) that need to [be killed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620/how-do-you-kill-all-current-connections-to-a-sql-server-2005-database)?

Comment: What have you increased the connection parameter to? And how many connections do you see in the SDE.PROCESS_INFORMATION table?

Comment: I think there were 84 connections and I've changed them to 1000.

Comment: I used :"Detach Right click DB -> Tasks -> Detach... check "Drop Connections" Ok

Reattach Right click Databases -> Attach.. Add... -> select your database, and change the Attach As column to your desired database name. Ok  "    and I can now edit the data existing in my geodatabase, but I still cannot import other data.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using oracle data base, restart the service.it will work.